# How to unescape string in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I used SafeHtmlUtils.htmlEscape(text) and I want to use opposite function. Could you tell me if in gwt there is function like unescapeHtml()

Answer (score 9):

If (and please only if) you can trust the text not to contain malicious content, you can use

```java
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTML;

String unescaped = new HTML(text).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

If nothing has been done to do this trick (say some GWT project around), you can implement it in a JSNI method using javascript snip you can found here : [[CSS/HTML/Js] Unescaping HTML in javascript](http://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/?blogid=14)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted something easy to unit test so I implemented '*htmlUnescape()*' which reverses the effects of *SafeHtmlUtils.htmlEscape()* and *SafeHtmlBuilder.appendEscapedLines()*.  They all exist in the 'shared' package and work fine in a JVM.

This utility class might be useful to you...

```
private static class Replacer {
    private final String target;
    private final String replacement;
    private final RegExp re;

    private Replacer(String target, String replacement) {
        this.target = target;
        this.replacement = replacement;
        re = RegExp.compile(RegExp.quote(target), "g");
    }

    public String process(String s) {
        if (s.contains(target)) return re.replace(s, replacement);
        return s;
    }
}
```