# GWT / JS - Decode ascii characters like apostrophe from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, gwt, character-encoding

I am using GWT and an external service that returns a JSON response that contains special characters as ASCII html, for ex. the apostrophe is ' I need to properly unescape the response string so that the characters will be properly displayed.

So far, the only solution I found is:

```
String unescaped = new HTML(text).getText();
```

but it seems a little weird.

Is there another way, that doesn't include for example creation of widgets (html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's really the most straight-forward way.
Yes, you're creating a temporary `div`, but there's nothing "weird" in that, not in a web framework like GWT at least.

Of course, you can always use some external library, like Apache Commons' `StringEscapeUtils`; or implement your own method to do it (though that'd be reinventing the wheel); or any of the other solutions found in [a very similar question posted 5 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537003/how-to-unescape-string-in-gwt) <sup>(of which yours is a clear duplicate and I should be flagging it as such, but whatever)</sup>.